# Instantiating an undo method for two different moves

Tags: java, stack, overloading

I was wondering if you could help me. I have a puzzle that needs to implement an undo method. There are two moves you can complete an assign move (assigns a number to the grid) and a relation move (which adds a relation move).

I have an abstract class (UserEntry) which instantiates one common method with Assign and RelEntry. I have called this public void addToPuzzle() {

it is as follows in the Assign Class:

```
@Override
public void addToPuzzle() {
    Assign a = new Assign(row, col, num);
}
```

and this in the RelEntry Class:

```
@Override
public void addToPuzzle() {
   RelEntry re = new RelEntry(greaterRow, greaterCol, lesserRow, lesserCol);
}
```

I am trying to create an undo method in my puzzle UI using a stack. I have tried this:

```
private void undo() {
    if(stack.empty())
    return;
    stack.pop().addToPuzzle();
}
```

Moves are instantiated in the puzzle UI and I have pushed each move in the text UI into the stack using a stack.push line of code following each move being assigned. I have a feeling I'm not being clear, if this is the case, go easy on me as I'm new to Java.

Comment: What is your question or problem here?

Comment: You might want to take a look at Command Design Pattern
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/command_pattern.htm

Comment: I'm trying to create an undo method in my text based UI for two different data types.

Comment: My question is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65074638/how-to-extract-information-from-java-stack-as-individual-data-types-and-use-in-m I just need more information on how to create the undo move in the Puzzle UI.

Comment: @user7 yeah, I've done that but when I execute undo it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Since you push two moves, you have to pop two times.